# jquery toggle function in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

Hi I'm currently facing this problem. I have some tab contents in 6 tabs. On load it will display the first tab content. I want to toggle between 1 tab such that when i click again it will hide. but the problem is when I clicked again, the remaining 5 tabs that are hidden are shown. how do I go about hiding the first tab content using toggle() without displaying the other 5 tabs content.

currently here's what I have written.

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".tabContent").toggle();      
});
```

And here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/85/)

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code or provide a jfiddle?

Comment: you can put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `$(".tabContent")` refers to all the tabs. You need to use a more specific selector, something that refers to `$(this)`.

Comment: In all likelihood, you'll need to more carefully scope your `$(".tabContent").toggle()` call, but it's impossible to tell without a more thorough example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/85/ here's my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eMLTB/98/

```
$("li").each(function(){//use .each() to call all list item element one by one
    $(this).click(function(){// create click function
        var i = $(this).find("a").attr("href");//get href attribute
        $(i).toggle();//get div element by Id and call toggle()
    });
});
```

--

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to add either `return false;` or `event.preventDefault();` inside the function.